# How to upload a file to a GitHub repos using REST API

Tags: github, github-api

I have Java code that submits a file to Bitbucket and creates a pull request. I need to port it to GitHub. In Bitbucket the API takes a form post for a file submission:

```java
    public void storeMessageInBitbucket(final Vertx vertx, final String message,
            final String accessToken) {

        // Convert to HTTP Form format as used by Bitbucket API
        final String messagePath = "/src/newStuff/randomFilename.json";

        final MultiMap form = MultiMap.caseInsensitiveMultiMap();
        form.set("author", "john.doe@unknown.com");
        form.set("message", "new Comment");
        form.set("branch", "comments-new");
        form.set(messagePath, message);

        final WebClientOptions options = new WebClientOptions()
                .setUserAgent("CommentService 1.0.4")
                .setSsl(true)
                .setKeepAlive(true);

        final WebClient wc = WebClient.create(vertx, options);
        final String target = "/2.0/repositories/myuser/myrepo/src";
        wc.post(443, "api.bitbucket.org", target).ssl(true)
                .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .putHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                .sendForm(form)
                .onSuccess(resp -> System.out.printf("Posted to %s%n", messagePath))
                .onFailure(err -> System.err.println(err.getMessage()));

    }
```

Similar the submission of a PR:

```java
    public void createPullRequest(final Vertx vertx, final String message,
            final String accessToken) {

        // Compose pull request data
        final JsonObject source = new JsonObject()
                .put("branch", new JsonObject().put("name", "comments-new"))
                .put("repository", new JsonObject().put("full_name", "myuser/myrepo"));

        final JsonObject destination = new JsonObject()
                .put("branch", new JsonObject().put("name", "master"));

        // Final assembly
        final JsonObject body = new JsonObject();
        body.put("title", "Comment from John Doe");
        body.put("source", source);
        body.put("destination", destination);
        body.put("close_source_branch", true);

        final WebClientOptions options = new WebClientOptions()
                .setUserAgent("CommentService 1.0.4")
                .setSsl(true)
                .setKeepAlive(true);

        final WebClient wc = WebClient.create(vertx, options);

        final String target = "/2.0/repositories/myuser/myrepo/pullrequests/";

        wc.post(443, "api.bitbucket.org", target).ssl(true)
                .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .putHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                .sendJson(body)
                .onSuccess(res -> System.out.println("Pull request is on its way"))
                .onFailure(err -> System.err.println(err.getMessage()));
    }
```

I looked at [the github CLI](https://cli.github.com/) and the [GitHub REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest?apiVersion=2022-11-28) which does address [creating a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/pulls?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-pull-request), but I couldn't find how to upload a file.

Where could I find the matching documentation and/or a sample?s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload a file to a repository see https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-file-contents

Comment: Thx. That was what I was missing